# Michael Moorcock Eternal Champion book with Norse theme and six 'planes'

Tags: story-identification, michael-moorcock, eternal-champion

I remember reading a Michael Moorcock Eternal Champion book in mid-1980's with a kind-of medieval Norse theme and six separate 'planes', but can't figure out what the title is. Here are some details I remember:

- The planes had Germanic sounding names all ending in 'heim', like 'Flugensheim'
- People can travel between the planes at specific transit points, like wormholes
- On one plane, people travelled around on wooden tall-ships, but on land; the ship had a dimensional warp effect on nearby land, so they would pass any nearby stuff (towns, forests, etc.) without damaging them
- The leader on that plane had a gigantic, elaborate hat that was borderline unmanageable and therefore ridiculous
- Another plane was inhabited by benign ascetics who are always weeping blood from their eyes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The Dragon in the Sword](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2068) by Michael Moorcock. It's the third book in the Erekosë series.

After the events of Phoenix in Obsidian Urlik Skarsol sails on the Dark ship to Maaschanheem, the Six Realms of the Wheel, where he becomes *Prince Flamadin*. The six realms are:

> “As his highness knows,” said Armiad with barely restrained impatience, “we are Six Realms, the Realms of the Wheel. There is Maaschanheem, which is this Realm. There is Draachenheem, which is where Prince Flamadin rules (when not adventuring elsewhere!),” a nod to me, “and Gheestenheem, Realm of the Cannibal Ghost Women. The other three Realms are Barganheem, claimed by the mysterious Ursine Princes, Fluugensheem, whose people are guarded by the Flying Island, and Rootsenheem, whose warriors have skins of glowing blood. There is also, of course, the Realm of the Centre itself, but none comes from there nor ventures there. We call it Alptroomensheem, Realm of the Nightmare Marches. Are you fully reminded now, Count von Bek?

The silly hat is worn by *Baron Captain Armiad-naam-Sliforg-ig-Vortan*. He is the captain of the ship that carries John Daker/Flamadin to the port of Massing:

> He held a skull-cap across a chest covered in the most elaborate red, gold and blue brocade and on his thick legs were flaring breeches weighted at the bottoms with heavy balls of differently coloured felt. On his head was one of the strangest hats I had ever seen in all my rangings through the multiverse, and it was no wonder he did not choose to use this for the ritualistic covering of the heart. The hat was at least a yard high, very much like an old-fashioned stovepipe but with a narrower brim. I guessed that it was stiffened from inside, yet nonetheless it tended to lean wildly in more than one direction and it was coloured a garish mustard yellow so bright I feared it would blind me.

The people apparently weeping blood are the *Red Weepers* who inhabit the plane called *Rootsenheem*:

> I could now more clearly see the men’s faces. Their eyes were wide and staring, rimmed entirely in red. Their helmets shaded their faces but I could now see that under each eye on a kind of wire frame was suspended a small cup. With a frisson of nausea I realised that the eyes were constantly exuding a viscous red fluid, a kind of mucus, and that the men themselves stared blindly at us.

There is a description of the events in the book
on [the Moorcock's Multiverse Wikia here](https://stormbringer.fandom.com/wiki/Prince_Flamadin).

Comment: Great answer John, thanks!